# iPhone with iOS 10 not detected by xcode 8 beta or itunes

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, xcode8

I upgraded an iPhone 5 to iOS10.

When plugged in, it is not detected by neither xcode (organizer and whatnot) nor itunes.

Known facts :

- pluging the device to my mac makes the device battery charge. However the popup "trust this computer ?" does not show
- I have xcode 8-beta installed

What I've tried so far :

- tried with another cable
- tried on other mac
- same cable but another iPhone (ios9.x) : detected as wanted (itunes & xcode)
- reset main settings
- reboot the ihpone in recovery mode : still nothing

Another side-problem is that I can't downgrade to iOS9. If I understand correctly the procedure, one has to plug the device to iTunes in order to downgrade to iOS 9.

I think the problem is this device, prior to upgrading to iOS10, was not registered neither in iTunes nor xcode. Maybe that's the problem ... not sure :( And no idea what to do next.

Comment: This is not a programming question. I think, the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for this question.

Comment: There are a lot of similar question if you browser the xcode tag. Thanks for the tip, I think the Apple Forums is the where I should have posted.